# Series of sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, recurrence-relations

Given the recursively defined sequence
$$
a_2 = 2(C+1)a_0
$$
and
$$
a_{n+2}=\frac{\left(n(n+6)+4(C+1)\right)a_n - 8(n-2)a_{n-2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}.
$$
that I got from the Frobenius method applied to an ODE, where for every odd $n$ we have $a_n=0$.
This brought me to the following problem:

For which $C\in \mathbb{R}$ do we have that $|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n |< \infty$?
 Of course, there is a trivial solution $C=-1$, but are there more available?

Edit: Furthermore, it was explained in the comments below that the convergence (due to linearity) is independent of the initial value $a_0$, so we could also just set this one $=1$.

If anything is unclear, please let me know. Since nobody answered so far, I just wanted to say that also interesting observations are highly appreciated.

Comment: The defining equations are homogeneous in the $a_j$, and so the value of $a_0$ is irrelevant (other than the trivial $a_0=0$): for a given $C$, if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges for some particular $a_0\ne0$, then it converges for every $a_0$.

Comment: There are several things I noticed in your previous post. (a) The second ODE without a 2 multiplying $x\frac{d}{dx}$ is not selfadjoint. (b) How did find that the second ODE was equivalent to the first. (c) Why are not you looking at both independent power series solutions? (d) Why do you believe that there must be endpoint conditions that you can specify? Both endpoints are most likely in the limit point case which means square-integrability near the endpoints is the best you can expect, and maybe only at one of the two endpoints. Trying to deal with 2 limit-point endpoints is not simple.

Comment: @T.A.E. Hi, nice to hear from you.(b) I think I substituted $f(t) = g(t)e^{2t^2}$ in the second ODE( did this with a CAS) and got the first one (c+d) Well, the boundary conditions are periodic ones motivated from physics. I mean sure, if you are able to construct square integrable solutions with the same limit behaviour then this would be fine, too (but I don't see so far how that could have simplified the calculation). But sure, if you know how to do it for a slightly more general case, then this would help a lot.

Comment: @user180097 : I've been rather occupied lately. A Sturm-Liouville equation requires symmetric form, which means that you need an integrating factor. $(1-x^{2})\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}-x\frac{d}{dx}$ is not in symmetric form, whereas an extra $2$ by the derivative gives $\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{d}{dx}$, which is symmetric. Without symmetric form, all bets are off. The weight function factors into the inner-product you have to use. There's a dimension one space of $(L-iI)f=0$ where $f$ is weighted square-integrable at $0$ and the same goes for $x=1$. You're lucky if $f$ is integ. at $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: If you do get $f$ that is square-integrable at both endpoints, then I think you'll get boundedness of $f$, and a limit at both endpoints. The issue of what happens for real eigenvalues is more questionable. As with Legendre polynomials, you don't get to pick periodicity--that happened naturally. Endpoint conditions are not something you can choose for the Legendre polynomials--you get what you get because you don't have two such eigenfunctions for $\lambda=n(n+1)$. The same thing probably happens here. Had Legendre end conditions been possible, they would have been non-physical, an artifact.

Comment: @user180097: I will try to look more at the endpoint issues later, but just wanted you to know the general issues that are well-understand. Constructing the solutions by power series solutions will get all of them because you're expanding around the regular point $x=0$. And, I suspect that the good solutions will be bounded at both endpoints, and can probably prove it. Because of Abel's theorem on power series, that will likely force a condition on the coefficients at $x=\pm 1$, and that will determine acceptable $C$. I think you're already correctly on that track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reduced equation is
$$
( -x^2+1 ) \frac {{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}x^2} f
 ( x ) -x \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x} f ( x ) +4
 ( 2x^2-1+ ( 2x^2-1 )^2+C ) f
 ( x ) =0.
$$
**Symmetry and Spectral Theory:** This is not in symmetric Sturm-Liouville form, which is required in order to do meaningful spectral theory. There are two ways to put it into symmetric form: by letting $f=\rho g$ and choosing $\rho$, or by multiplying everything on the left by some $\rho$. The second is easier, but the first method is in keeping with how to transform the associated Legendre equation into the form encountered through separation of variables of the Laplacian in spherical coordinates. So, that's the one I'll use, because of this parallel. Let $f=\rho g$, and divide by $\rho$ on the left. The above equation becomes
$$
\begin{align}
   &(1-x^{2})g''+2(1-x^{2})\frac{\rho'}{\rho}g'+(1-x^{2})\frac{\rho''}{\rho} g \\
   &-xg'-x\frac{\rho'}{\rho}g + \\
   &+4(2x^{2}-1+(2x^{2}-1)^{2}+C)g=0.
\end{align}
$$
Now choose $\rho$ so that the terms involving $g''$, $g'$ become $\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{d}{dx}$. Equivalently,
$$
          2(1-x^{2})\frac{\rho'}{\rho}-x=-2x,\\
            \frac{\rho'}{\rho}=\frac{-x}{2(1-x^{2})}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{(1-x^{2})'}{(1-x^{2})},\\
             \rho = (1-x^{2})^{1/4}.
$$
Then the equation becomes
$$
         \frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{d}{dx}g+(1-x^{2})\frac{\rho''}{\rho}g-x\frac{\rho'}{\rho}g+4(2x^{2}-1+(2x^{2}-1)^{2}+C)g=0
$$
We already have $\rho'/\rho$. Differentiating $\rho'/\rho$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
       \left(\frac{\rho'}{\rho}\right)' & =\frac{\rho''}{\rho}-\left(\frac{\rho'}{\rho}\right)^{2}, \\
      \frac{\rho''}{\rho} & =\left(\frac{\rho'}{\rho}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\rho'}{\rho}\right)' \\
& = \frac{x^{2}}{4(1-x^{2})^{2}}-\frac{2(1+x^{2})}{4(1-x^{2})^{2}}
 = -\frac{2+x^{2}}{4(1-x^{2})^{2}}
\end{align}
$$
Finally,
$$
    (1-x^{2})\frac{\rho''}{\rho}-x\frac{\rho'}{\rho}=-\frac{2+x^{2}}{4(1-x^{2})}+\frac{x^{2}}{2(1-x^{2})}=-\frac{2-x^{2}}{1-x^{2}}=-1-\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}.
$$
The transformed equation becomes
$$
    \frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{d}{dx}g-\left(1+\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\right)g+4(2x^{2}-1+(2x^{2}-1)^{2}+C)g=0.
$$
The Legendre equation obtained from the Laplacian through separation of variables in spherical coordinates looks like
$$
     \left[\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{m^{2}}{1-x^{2}}+n(n+1)\right]g = 0.
$$
So this resembles the Associated Legendre Equation of order $m=1$. And the solutions you want will have the form $f=\rho g=(1-x^{2})^{1/4}g$. It is reasonable to expect that the values of $C$ should be asymptotic to $\frac{1}{4}(n(n+1)-1)$. Solutions $g_{1}$, $g_{2}$ for distinct values of $C$ will be orthogonal in the sense that
$$
           \int_{-1}^{1}g_{1}g_{2}\,dx = 0,
$$
provided that you can find $g_{j}$ which are square-integrable at *both* endpoints (I suspect you can because of the symmetry you noted.) So, in the setting in which you are interested, it is natural to seek solutions $f_{j}=(1-x^{2})^{1/4}g_{j}$ which satisfy
$$
             \int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{-1/2}f_{j}^{2}\,dx < \infty,
$$
and you should expect to automatically have orthogonality in the following sense:
$$
              \int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{-1/2}f_{1}f_{2}\,dx = 0.
$$
Look into the Associated Legendre Polynomials http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials for $m=1$:
$$
    P_{n}^{m}=\frac{(-1)^{m}}{2^{n}n!}(1-x^{2})^{m/2}\frac{d^{m+n}}{dx^{m+n}}(x^{2}-1)^{n}.
$$
These are the asymptotics I would expect: $f = (1-x^{2})^{1/4}g \sim (1-x^{2})^{1/4}P_{n}^{1}$. Note that for $m=1$, $P_{n}^{m}$ are not really polynomials.

**Power Series Solutions:** The goal of putting the equation into symmetric form, while it does lead to orthogonality and spectral (eigenvalue) information, seems to work against power series solutions in this particular case. To get rid of the singular terms at $x=\pm 1$, look instead at the indicial equation at these endpoints. It is enough to look at $x=-1$ because of symmetry. The equation has the approximate form
$$
      (1+x)(2)\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}f+\frac{d}{dx}f=0.
$$
The indicial equation is found by setting $f=(1+x)^{\rho}$ and solving for $\rho$ such that
$$
               2\rho(\rho-1)+\rho=0\implies \rho=0 \mbox{ or } \rho=1/2.
$$
The one with the larger real part is significant. So we expect that $f=(1-x^{2})^{1/2}g$ is the only form that could possibly lead to a power series $g$ which would be holomorphic across $x=\pm 1$. Here the goals of spectral theory and of finding nice solutions near the endpoints do not coincide. But, the same is true for the general Legendre equation, too. The functions $P_{n}^{1}$ have a factor of $(1-x^{2})^{1/2}$ times a polynomial. That's a sanity check that setting $f=(1-x^{2})^{1/2}g$ has a chance of leading to a polynomial $g$, an entire function $g$, or at least to function $g$ which remains controlled near the endpoints. Any such case would be significant to what you want, and the special values of $C$ required to gain control over $g$ are the expected eigenvalues.

So the next step is to substitute $f=(1-x^{2})^{1/2}g$ into the equation at the very top of this post. What I found is
$$
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\left((1-x^{2})\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}-x\frac{d}{dx}\right)(\sqrt{1-x^{2}}g)=\left((1-x^{2})\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}-3x\frac{d}{dx}-1\right)g.
$$
The cancellation of negative powers of $1-x^{2}$ is nice and somewhat expected. The new equation for $g=f/\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$ is
$$
      (1-x^{2})g''-3xg'+4\left\{(2x^{2}-1)+(2x^{2}-1)^{2}+C-\frac{1}{4}\right\}g = 0,\\
   (1-x^{2})g''-3xg'+(16x^{4}-8x^{2}+4C-1)g=0.
$$
Set $g=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ and substitute into the equation:
$$
     \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n}
    -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3na_{n}x^{n}\\
    +\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}16a_{n-4}x^{n}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}8a_{n-2}x^{n}+(4C-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}=0.
$$
The complete set of coefficient conditions leaves $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ arbitrary:
$$
\begin{align}
   x^{0}:\; & 2a_{2}+(4C-1)a_{0}=0 \\
            & a_{2}=\frac{1}{2}(1-4C)a_{0} \\
   x^{1}:\; & 6a_{3}-3a_{1}+(4C-1)a_{1}=0 \\
            & a_{3}=\frac{1}{6}(4-4C)a_{1} \\
   x^{2}:\; & 12a_{4}-2a_{2}-6a_{2}-8a_{0}+(4C-1)a_{2}=0\\
            & a_{4}=\frac{1}{12}(9-4C)a_{2}+\frac{8}{12}a_{0}
            = \frac{1}{4!}(1^{2}-4C)(3^{2}-4C)a_{0}+\frac{8}{(4)(3)}a_{0}\\
   x^{3}:\; & 20a_{5}-6a_{3}-9a_{3}-8a_{1}+(4C-1)a_{3}=0\\
            & a_{5}=\frac{1}{20}(16-4C)a_{3}+\frac{8}{20}a_{1}
            = \frac{1}{5!}(2^{2}-4C)(4^{2}-4C)a_{1}+\frac{8}{(5)(4)}a_{1}\\
   x^{n}:\; & (n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}-n(n-1)a_{n}-3na_{n}+16a_{n-4}-8a_{n-2}+(4C-1)a_{n}=0\\
            & a_{n+2}=\frac{(n+1)^{2}-4C}{(n+1)(n+2)}a_{n}-\frac{8}{(n+1)(n+2)}a_{n-2}
           +\frac{16}{(n+1)(n+2)}a_{n-4}.
\end{align}
$$
I don't have enough time to push this forward to a pattern for the general term, but it looks promising ... will come back to it. This looks more like the Legendre arguments that I thought it would. Superficially it looks like the convergence is changed when $C$ takes on certain values. Please check if everything looks okay to you ...

**Eigenfunction Conditions:** This is a little messy. The original $f$ in your reduced equation gives rise to $g=(1-x^{2})^{-1/4}f$ which is a solution of
$$
     Lg=-\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{d}{dx}g+\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}g-(16x^{2}-8x^{2}-1)g=4Cg.
$$
The natural domain is where $(Lg,g)$ exists, where this is the $L^{2}[-1,1]$ inner-product. Integrating by parts gives
$$
          (Lg,g)=\|\sqrt{1-x^{2}}g'\|^{2}+\|g/\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\|^{2}+\cdots.
$$
In other words, the natural conditions on the original $f$ are that
$$
           (1-x^{2})^{1/2}g'=(1-x^{2})^{1/2}((1-x^{2})^{-1/4}f)' \in L^{2}[-1,1],\\
           (1-x^{2})^{-1/2}g=(1-x^{2})^{-3/4}f \in L^{2}[-1,1].
$$
The power series $p$ for which the coefficient equations are given above is $p=(1-x^{2})^{-1/2}f$. Or, $f=(1-x^{2})^{1/2}p$, so the $p$ should satisfy
$$
     (1-x^{2})^{1/2}((1-x^{2})^{1/4}p)'=(1-x^{2})^{3/4}p'-\frac{x}{2}(1-x^{2})^{-1/4}p\in L^{2}[-1,1],\\
     (1-x^{2})^{-1/4}p \in L^{2}[-1,1].
$$
Equivalently,
$$
            \int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{3/2}|p'|^{2}\,dx < \infty,\;\;\;\;
            \int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^{-1/2}|p|^{2}\,dx < \infty.
$$
That means that the series solutions can diverge near the endpoints and still qualify as eigenfunctions, but not diverge too quickly. $p \sim (1-x^{2})^{-1/4}$ is borderline, and then $f=(1-x)^{1/2}p$ might be expected to vanish at $\pm 1$. That behavior should select out the correct eigenfunctions. One useful special case is
$$
     (1-x^{2})^{1/2}((1-x^{2})^{1/4}p)'\cdot (1-x^{2})^{-1/4}p \in L^{1} \\
   \implies \frac{d}{dx}((1-x^{2})^{1/4}p)^{2}\in L^{1}\\
   \implies (1-x^{2})^{1/2}p^{2} \mbox{ has limits at $x=\pm 1$ }.
$$
These limits must be $0$ because $\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}((1-x^{2})^{1/2}p^{2})=((1-x^{2})^{-1/4}p)^{2}\in L^{1}$. So these conditions are necessary for the eigenfunctions
$$
            \lim_{x\rightarrow\pm 1}(1-x^{2})^{1/4}p(x)=0.
$$

Comment: interesting answer so far. especially, the structural insight.

Comment: it's a model for a rotational motion in engineering where we expect a discrete spectrum of rotational modes. but isn't this problem (of finding $C$) quite similar to the one we started with ( although not exactly the same cause you used a different ODE?)

Comment: I used the ODE that you said was equivalent, did I not?

Comment: yes, but I don't see right now, where you want to go? I mean, we ended up with fairly the same problem we started with in my question.

Comment: by the way, I don't want to discourage you, your answer is very nice, but I don't see your intention behind all this.

Comment: Actually, if these are equivalent, then I highly doubt what you were given before. The values of $C$ should be mostly positive because $L=-\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^{2})\frac{d}{dx}$ is positive if we're talking about $L^{2}$ conditions on the domain. This is because $(Lf,f)=\|\sqrt{1-x^{2}}f'\|^{2} \ge 0$ follows from integration by parts (ignoring possible evaluation terms.) So the analysis is quite different.

Comment: I agree, I don't trust his values either( I  did not want to critizise his values, cause I did not know what he actually did and were not able to do it by myself, so). Especially, I failed verifying $C=1$ as a solution ( numerically!). But in principle the question remains: How to get the eigenvalues out of this sequence.

Comment: By the way: We also expect that for $n \rightarrow \infty, C \approx n^2$.

Comment: It will be necessary to find the general term of a series solution. Something meaningful should emerge. That means finding the general $a_{n}$ through induction. I haven't had time. Do my coefficient equations look right so far? I don't believe endpoint conditions are possible other than $L^{2}$ type conditions, which means the series will be the only clue. The series I have has more of a chance of revealing the problem because of being modeled after the Legendre analysis, and because the $\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$ term is gone, that would have affected convergence.

Comment: the problems is that I don't have a CAS ( I just have MATLAB available) available to check all terms, so I cannot guarantee correctness. I will be able to repeat your calculations on a CAS in about two weeks. By the way, I have awarded the bounty to you cause you are saying that you are currently quite busy. I highly appreciate your efforts here, so please take all the time you need :-)

Comment: I like looking at things like this, but it has to be done so carefully or everything is thrown off afterwards. Check, double check, triple check ... . I was fascinated by this problem because you don't see a lot of relevant new Sturm-Liouville systems, and random perturbations are not likely to work out very cleanly, but you said this is from a physical application. So that makes it interesting. I think the general pattern for $a_{n}$ will emerge; just have to have time to sit and look at $a_{5}, a_{7},a_{9},\cdots$ and $a_{4},a_{6},a_{8},\cdots$. You should try, too, if you have time.

Comment: I do. You may find it interesting to know that if you change one or two numbers in the ODE (I did this when I had a CAS around, so I cannot tell you exactly, what I had to change), you are able to write down explicite solutions that have the form $ \sum b_ix^{2i}\sqrt{\sum a_ix^{2i}} e^{x^2}$(finite!polynomials). . But apparently you don't always get these kind of solutions.(so, it was a product of a polynomial, a polynomial under a square root and this gaussian term.)

Comment: I should add that the case where I found solutions described the same physical complexity as this one does. so it was not that by changing these numbers, we would have neglected something in the model.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I did some MATLAB numerical calculations I found out that besides the ground state all higher eigenvalues have two eigenfunctions with the same eigenvalue. (at least up to the ten eigenfunctions I checked)

Comment: A couple of notes concerning the eigenfunctions are in the edited post. I'm now looking more at the series.

Comment: Okay, I surrender. The series terms will contain products of terms $n^{2}-4C$, and it sure seems that convergence of the series should be affected if $C=n/2$, but I cannot prove that to be the case. The $L^{2}$ conditions I gave you characterize one selfadjoint domain and, for that reason, there cannot be more than a countable number of eigenfunctions for which eigenfunctions satisfy these conditions. I'm not perfectly convinced there are any. It is possible for a perturbation of a singular problem like this to lead to continuous spectrum, even though I doubt that's the case here. I'm stuck.

Comment: thank you. well, there should be solutions cause you bring it to the form of a Schroedinger equation and I found some numerically, but okay. I am sure you did your best. This ODE is really a mess and I am grateful to everything you've written there above. :-)

Comment: When you look at the series solutions, you see all the terms with products of $(n^{2}-4C)$. If $n$ is even, then one such term vanishes if you use the even terms $a_{0},a_{2},\cdots$ and if $n$ is odd, then one such term vanishes if you use the odd terms. This is very much like the Associated Legendre situation, but I just can't see exactly how it ends up improving convergence near $\pm 1$ in those cases. It seems to me that it does, but I can't quite put my finger on it because of how many terms there are. It suggests the eigenvalues are $C=n/2$, but maybe there's a better choice of $C$.

Answer (score 3):

Just an observation for now.
If we set $b_k = a_{2k}$ then we have:
$$\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}=\left(1+\frac{10-10k-4C}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\right)+\frac{8(2k-2)}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\left(1-\frac{b_{k-1}}{b_k}\right),\tag{1}$$
where:
$$\left(1+\frac{10-10k-4C}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\right)=1-\frac{5}{2k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right),\quad \frac{8(2k-2)}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}=\frac{4}{k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right),$$
so assuming that $\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}$ behaves like $1-\frac{L}{k}$, it follows that $L=\frac{5}{2}$, hence $b_n\ll n^{-5/2}$ grants that $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

---

Moreover, if we set $h(x)=e^{4x^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}$ we have that the original ODE
$$(1-x^2)\,f''+x\,(7-8x^2)\,f'+4(C+1)\,f=0\tag{2}$$
is mapped into:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(h\cdot f'\right) = -4(C+1)\frac{h\cdot f}{1-x^2}.\tag{3}$$
Maybe the last equation is easier to solve by decomposing $h$ and $f$ with respect to a base of orthogonal polynomials (Legendre polynomials or Chebyshev polynomials, having a well-known behaviour in $1$). It is worth noticing that the Fourier series of $h$ can be expressed in terms of values of a Bessel function, that are pretty fast decaying, hence approximated solutions should be not too difficult to write.